# Does the display of the Habsburg flag have any contemporary connotations in Austria or Hungary?

Tags: flag, hungary, austria

Numerous countries have historical flags which, when flown or otherwise celebrated, carry significant contemporary political connotations and are usually interpreted as a sign that the person flying said flag has a particular (usually staunchly conservative/right wing) Weltanschauung.  Obvious examples include the Confederate (battle) flag in the United States, the Red Ensign in Canada, the black-white-red tricolour in Germany, and the orange-white-blue flag of South Africa.  Left-wing equivalents include the DDR flag in Germany and the hammer-and-sickle in Russia.

I'm curious as to whether [the flag of the Habsburg empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_Habsburg_Monarchy) has any similar connotations in contemporary Austria, or indeed Hungary.  Would most contemporary citizens of Austria interpret a person flying this flag as having a particular viewpoint?  Or would it merely be viewed as a curiosity/eccentricity?

Comment: My guess is that it would not be used in Hungary for irredentist purposes because they have their own coat of arms and flag of the [earlier (independent) Kingdom of Hungary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Hungary_(1301%E2%80%931526)). That old coat of arms later appears on the [Austro-Hungarian flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austria-Hungary), after the [Austrian Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Austrian_Empire) was defeated by the Prussians in 1866, forcing some political changes.

Comment: The FPÖ apparently had some [weird ideas](https://budapestbeacon.com/right-wing-candidate-for-president-of-austria-wants-to-unite-former-habsburg-lands/) about recreating the Austrian Empire of sorts, but I see no mention of them using the Habsburg flag (in that article). Apparently Orban's government was sympathetic to FPÖ's proposals.

Comment: In parts of southern Poland that used to be part of Austria-Hungary (Galicja), it would most likely be seen as a curiosity. There is some nostalgic feeling about those times, because even though Austria was seen as a foreign occupier, it gave the region considerable autonomy. Moreover, Polish culture could flourish there to a much greater degree than in areas occupied by Prussia and Russia. But I don't think anybody would seriously want to recreate new Austria-Hungary there.

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any connotation attached to the display of the Habsburg colours, at least in Austria. The display of the Habsburg flag is highly unlikely to be interpreted as a nationalist statement, rather as an acknowledgement of an area's imperial past. For example, the flag might be displayed at mediaeval fairs such as the *"[Zeitreise ins Mittelalter Eggenburg](https://www.zeitreise-ins-mittelalter.at/)"* (Time-travel to the middle-ages).

One reason for this is that the Habsburg family is still extant, and still uses the colours; for example at the [funeral](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/people/news/hapsburg-goes-to-his-grave-amid-ruritanian-pageant-2315168.html) of Otto von Habsburg, the last Crown Prince of Austria-Hungary in 2011, the coffin was draped with the flag. Current members of the house also use the colours - for example, Ferdinand Habsburg [incorporates](https://www.krone.at/458330) the scheme on his Formula Renault racing suit.

Another reason is that the black-yellow colour scheme is likely to be confused with the colours of the German region of [Swabia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swabia) - the close proximity of the region to Austria means that this association is more likely.

[image]

Finally, contemporary Austrian nationalist sentiment tends to be associated with the national flag of Austria - see the pictures of adverts for the FPÖ from this [article](https://www.ft.com/content/f02bbad2-ec29-11e9-a240-3b065ef5fc55).

Comment: I guess many Austrians, if you would ask them on the street, couldn't even name the Habsburg colours, let alone develop any sentiments upon seeing a Habsburg coloured flag.

Answer (score 3):

It is a conservative statement to carry symbols of the Habsburg monarchy, definitely. But the flag is rarely brandished, unlike the coat of arms, which can be seen sometimes.